# How to box math in text without it going to display style while in the inline math environment?

Tags: box

So I'm trying to box something like `$\frac{1}{10}$`, but when I do `$\boxed{1}{10}$`, it puts the fraction in display style. However, this is not ideal for the formatting of my paper. How do I avoid this? I couldn't find any similar questions and I tried all the boxing commands I know and could find.

Edit: How do I do this while staying in the math environment, ex:
$\frac{1-\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^\infty}{10}={\frac{1}{10}}.$

Also, can someone explain why it's not converting the above to latex?

This is what happens when I true to use \fbox:

`$\frac{1-\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^\infty}{10}=\fbox{\frac{1}{10}}.$`

[image]

Comment: `\fbox{$\frac{1}{10}$}` ?

Comment: I assume this works, but I am already in the math environment, not text. So doing \fbox doesn't really work...

Comment: why not? unless you arein a subscript in which case `\text{\fbox{$\frac...`

Comment: we do no enable mathjax on this site, if you want to show output add an image

Comment: what  part of `$\frac{1-\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^\infty}{10}={\frac{1}{10}}.$` do you want to box, and why can you not use `\fbox` as suggested?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want the ```\frac{1}{10}``` boxed and when I use \fbox it bugs out.

Comment: "bugs out" is not anything we can debug.  it should work, if not post a complete example document and show the error message from the log file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Updated the original post.

Comment: Look at what David did in the first comment and compare to your code, see if you can tell what is missing. The code you provided does not compile because of what is missing from David's comment

Comment: But I already am in the inline math environment? I can't add more $ because I'm already in it? Sorry, I'm really new to latex and vague answers are super unhelpful.

Comment: The contents inside `\fbox` is **always** text mode no matter where it is used. Thus you still need math **inside** it.

Comment: @daleif Thank you! Why did that take over an hour to solve? That's all I needed to know. I get really frustrated when I ask a simple question and people purposely give me vague answers and waste my time. I spent time trying to figure this out on my own, but I couldn't, so I asked. So why are people wasting my time when the answer is literally one line. Come on man...

Comment: Because you did not show appropriate code, then we have no idea what you're doing. If you look on the site the most common comment is asking for appropriate code. Without it we cannot help much. Besides David did give you the answer in the very first comment.

Comment: @jackson Getting help for free online and then accusing the people who went out of their way to help you of wasting your time is dreadful behavior. People here are not mind readers who magically know what it is you're confused about; the first comment gave you good advice which you partly ignored. Your issue got solved. No one here owes you anything. Be grateful instead.

Comment: Sorry for coming off like that. I am new to this site, and everyone always leaves vague answers half the time. I didn't understand the first comment, as evidenced by what I said after. So I didn't really ignore it, just didn't understand it. Saying wasting time was rude of me, you are right. I apologize for that. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: OP took it for granted that the `\fbox` parameter is processed in the outer math mode and other people took it for granted that this parameter is in text mode. The result is: misunderstanding.

Comment: @jackson no harm done, but the initial comments were not  "vague" they exactly answered the question as originally posted. We can not guess what you do in your document if you do not show it, nor show the error that you got. Please _always_ include a complete small test document  in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code

```
$\frac{1-\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^\infty}{10}=\fbox{\frac{1}{10}}.$
```

prints the error message

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.7 ...}{8}\right)^\infty}{10}=\fbox{\frac{1}{10}}
                                                  .$
```

Yes, it is not clear enough for LaTeX users if they have no knowledge about TeX itself. I try to explain this in more detail.

The LaTeX macro `\fbox` puts its parameter into `\hbox` primitive, i.e. `\fbox{text}` does (besides others things) `\hbox{text}`. And `\hbox` TeX primitive opens group, starts internal horizontal mode, reads `text` and creates horizontal list from it, closes group and creates a box from created horizontal list and puts it to the current built list. The important is: **it opens internal horizontal mode**. It is (roughly speaking) a text mode which will be not broken to the lines in a paragraph. And it is not math mode. Modes are opened and closed in TeX using stack principle.

The LaTeX macro `\frac{A}{B}` does (roughly speaking) `{A\over B}` where `\over` is TeX primitive which can be used only in math mode. I.e. your code `\fbox{\frac{1}{10}}` does:

```
\hbox{{1\over 10}}
```

The `1` can be printed in internal horizontal mode. Then the `\over` is scanned but it cannot be used in internal horizontal mode. TeX suggests to insert `$` here in order to open the math mode. It is said in the error message. Now, the `$\over 10}` is scanned. The `}` here does not match with opening `{` because there is inserted `$`. We can see second error message:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\frac  #1#2->{\begingroup #1\endgroup \over #2}
```

And there are more similar errors here.

The correct code should be:

```
$\frac{1-\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^\infty}{10}=\fbox{$\frac{1}{10}$}.$
```

as mentioned in the first comment. You can see the stack principle of modes here. The first `$` opens math mode, the `\fbox{$\frac{1}{10}$}` expands to

```
\hbox{$1\over 10$}
```

and `\hbox` opens internal horizontal mode, then `$` opens next math mode and second `$` closes it, creates math list, converts it to the horizontal list and returns to the internal horizontal mode opened by `\hbox`. Then `\hbox` completes the horizontal list, closes internal horizontal mode and returns to the outer math mode, i.e. the created box is inserted into the current built math list as a single element.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm sorry for being rude to others, and this cleared up a lot for me. What's a good way to understand the foundations of TeX? I'm really lacking with that and I want to get better.

Comment: @jackson For example, you can see my text TeX in a Nutshell http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much! I will read this!

Comment: This would use textstyle in every case.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, `amsmath` defines `\boxed` to always use `\displaystyle`.

It's not really difficult to redefine it so that it uses the current math style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% from amsmath.sty
%\newcommand{\boxed}[1]{\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}
% now we redefine it
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\boxed}[1]{\mathpalette\boxed@{#1}}
\newcommand{\boxed@}[2]{\fbox{\m@th$#1#2$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\frac{1-\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^\infty}{10}=\boxed{\frac{1}{10}}.$

\[
\frac{1-\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^\infty}{10}=\boxed{\frac{1}{10}}.
\]

$x_{\boxed{y}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a different version where the separation between the rules and the material inside is smaller in script style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% from amsmath.sty
%\newcommand{\boxed}[1]{\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}
% now we redefine it
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\boxed}[1]{\mathpalette\boxed@{#1}}
\newcommand{\boxed@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \boxed@sep{#1}% set \fboxsep according to the style
  \fbox{\m@th$#1#2$}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\boxed@sep}[1]{% fix the lengths to suit
  \settowidth{\fboxsep}{$\m@th#1\mspace{1mu}\nonscript\mspace{3mu}$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\frac{1-\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^\infty}{10}=\boxed{\frac{1}{10}}.$

\[
\frac{1-\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)^\infty}{10}=\boxed{\frac{1}{10}}.
\]

$x_{\boxed{y}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]